# unable to create react new project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

i was trying to create a new react project after installed the necessary packs "node.js" i ran code for creating the app as guided in the tutorial but the app does not created.this is the error message having receiving.

```
$ npm install -g create-react-app
C:\Users\LADE\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-react-app -> C:\Users\LADE\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js
+ create-react-app@3.3.1
added 41 packages from 32 contributors, removed 9 packages and updated 15 packages in 52.883s

LADE@DESKTOP-O0URVQ6 MINGW64 /c/wamp64/www
$ cd react-app/
bash: cd: react-app/: No such file or directory

LADE@DESKTOP-O0URVQ6 MINGW64 /c/wamp64/www
$ npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\wamp64\www\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\wamp64\www\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\LADE\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-01T03_01_13_432Z-debug.log
```

please help me with this. i don't understand as i am new to this.

Answer (score 2):

You have not created a react application. 
Your first command installed the `create-react-app` globally.

```
$ npm install -g create-react-app
```

You then try to `cd` (Change Directory) into a directory `react-app` which does not exist with the command

```
$ cd react-app
```

What you want to do is simply run this command before the other commands

```
$ npx create-react-app react-app
```

Then you can issue the following commands

```
$ cd react-app
$ npm run start
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the create-react-app command with the name of the application that you want to build, eg:

```js
$ npx create-react-app name-of-your-app
```

Note that you use 'npx' so that create-react-app doesn't have to be installed locally. After running that command a new directory with the same name as your app is automatically created with all of the files in it.

Also it's a good idea to test that you installed Node correctly. To test this just check the version using the following command line prompts. If it prints the version then you know you installed it correctly:

```js
$ node --version
$ npm --version
```

Answer (score 0):

You have successfully installed `create-react-app`, **which is a popular toolchain for creating react based application.**

`npm start` command is used to start your standard react app. But in this case, you haven't created a react app yet. That's why it's giving you an error.

So to create a react app, you have already installed `create-react-app` toolchain. The first step is done.

Now type `npx create-react-app my-first-app` in your terminal. It will take some time to create your react app.

> Take note that you can call your react app anything you want (in this case its `my-first-app`), but make
>   sure that all characters of your react app name are lowercase.

Once its done creating your app, it will give you a success message. After that, you need to run `cd my-first-app` in your terminal.

Then you can run `npm start` to start your application.

Comment: If you want to learn more: https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app

Answer (score -1):

Run all the commands with Administrator access to your Terminal/Command Prompt. I was getting the same errors until I ran all the code with Admin access.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).